# Decoding ogg files to wav in WP8

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8, ogg, nvorbis

I want to convert ogg file to wav and then play it on wp8 devives.
I've already checked many solutions but none of them worked. This looks promising but something doesn't work:

```
string _audioPath = "/SomeProject;component/Sounds/a_dog.ogg";
var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(_audioPath, UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
using (var vorbis = new NVorbis.VorbisReader(stream, true))
        {
            float[] buf = new float[vorbis.TotalSamples];
            vorbis.ReadSamples(buf, 0, (int)vorbis.TotalSamples);
        }
```

When I execute it I see FileNotFoundException at VorbisReader contruction. I also checked if stream is readable and it is. I was able to get the file content using Read method.

Do you have any ideas why it doesn't work? Maybe you know some other library for wp8 which can decode ogg files?

[EDIT] I downloaded source code of NVorbis and used it directly from my project, and when i do this I don't get any FileNotFoundExceptions and everything seems to work. Maybe this exception is caused by missing library? I've got NVorbis reference added...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into the same issue as [this guy](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5584c595-e7b2-47b1-b1d2-88045e996e25/why-does-this-soundplayer-call-fail-in-wpf-code-?forum=wpf).  Short version: I believe your Pack URI should be "pack://application:,,,/SomeProject;Component/Sounds/a_dog.ogg".  NVorbis is not actually throwing the exception itself, but is instead causing the resource stream to do so...

Comment: doesn't work. I tried this uri: @"pack://application:,,,/SomeProject;component/Sounds/a_dog.ogg" and it's crashing at the GetResourceStream with UriFormatException. Also I tried static resources but it returns byte[] not a stream so I couldn't use it.

Comment: Hrmm...  Can you post the stacktrace of the original error to pastebin or something?  It's almost certainly related to the XAML resource being in the app assembly, but I'm not certain how to fix it...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/krsWgwFf  
so it is not a problem with opening my ogg file, but some system lib...

Comment: It's probably due to the framework version you are targeting...  NVorbis is built using .Net 3.5SP1.  What framework version are you targeting in your project?

Comment: I can't find any info. I would expect it in properties of project, but theres nothing about .net version. Target OS was set to WP7.5, but I upgraded it to WP8 project.

Comment: I should've read your question again... WP8 is basically .Net 4.5 (though not the whole thing).  Try adding a version redirect to the app.config See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: On second thought, add it to NVorbis.dll.config instead... That "should" address the issue.

Comment: I don't have app.config or any other config for NVorbis. In Pacages/NVorbis.0.8.3.0/ I can find: NVorbis.0.8.3.0.nuspec and NVorbis.XML. Which one should I modify? Maybe I should change these lines:
<frameworkAssemblies>
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System" targetFramework="" />
</frameworkAssemblies>

Comment: You'll have to create the config file...  Add NVorbis.dll.config to your project, set it as content, then add paste in the contents from http://pastebin.com/YjP3ivRQ.  If I'm not mistaken, this should make the official build work.

Comment: I did what you proposed, but it didn't work - the same exception. I've also searched web for some examples of assembly binding on wp8 and it's not popular topic. Is it even possible for wp8?

Comment: OK, that's the limit of my knowledge...  The redirect is the right answer, but I don't know how to do it on WP8, apparently.  If you find out, please post it back here as an answer so others can benefit.